# making python programs "chat" via pipe

Tags: python, pipe, stdout, stdin, multiprocessing

I'm trying to make two processes communicate using a pipe.
I did this in the parent process:

```
process = subprocess.Popen(test, shell=True, stdin=subprocess.PIPE, stdout=subprocess.PIPE)

process.stdin.write("4\n");
output = process.stdout.read()
print output
```

and in the child process:

```
inp = raw_input()
integer = int(inp)
print integer**2
while(True):
    pass
```

I would expect the parent process to print 16... Unfortunately, it remains hanging without printing anything. Replacing the infinite loop by a sleep for 5 seconds makes the parent process be idle for 5 seconds and AFTER that print 16. 
This shows that the parent process only gets the output from the child after it terminated execution.

I'd like to know if it's possible to get input before programs finishes.
My idea is to go passing information via this pipe, getting input, processing it, and outputting the result in the pipe, so that the other can continue with processing.

Any help?
Thanks,

Manuel

Comment: Have you tried flushing the stream when you write the `"4\n"`?

Comment: Yes, that's not the problem. The child process actually gets that 4, and I've seen it because just after reading that input, I write it to a regular file, and then enter the infinite loop. The parent process is the one that blocks in the read() part.

Comment: Out of curiosity, why didn't you use `sys.stdin.readline()` in the child process?

Comment: Dunno, I always use that to read input from standard input... I don't know the difference, do you?

Comment: @Manuel: `raw_input` is more oriented for interactive use and it's also missing in Python3. The results should be the same.

Comment: What Python version are you using and on what operating system?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As suggested by [ndim](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3268410/making-python-programs-chat-via-pipe/3268636#3268636), do the folowing in the parent:

```
process.stdin.write("4\n")    
process.stdin.flush()    
output = process.stdout.readline()    
print output
```

You will also need to change the child:

```
inp = sys.stdin.readline()
integer = int(inp)
sys.stdout.write("%d\n", (integer ** 2,))
sys.stdout.flush()
```

I used `sys.stdin.readline` and `sys.stdout.write` as a matter of style.

I wrote [2 test programs](http://pastebin.com/kRaBuS9G) and they worked fine with python-2.6.4-27 on Fedora 13.

Comment: this doesn't fix the issue, but thanks for your help and style advice!

Comment: I had solved it but in a VERY ugly way. Your solution is simple and very clean! Thanks a lot. (you get the solution mark because I'll update my code to this...)

Comment: @Manuel: you're welcome! It was about time to nail this question.

Comment: This is fantastic, quite a lot more difficult to find a working example of this than you'd think! Actually, I couldn't get the example in question working, but the link to the 2 test programs works very well.

Answer (score 4):

I see a number of possible issues:

a) The child process never actually flushes its output and thus never actually sends its output to the parent.

b) The parent process runs its `read()` call before the child process has actually sent its output (flushed its output).

c) The parent process does a blocking `read()` which until EOF which effectively means it waits for the child to exit. The `subprocess.Popen` docs should mention whether this can be the case.

d) The parent process's `read()` call waits for a certain number of bytes (e.g. 1024) to arrive before it returns.

Probably having the parent do lots of `read(1)` calls and reassembling the bytes as they come in will fix the issue. Or using a higher level communication API, e.g. using datagrams instead of parsing byte streams.

Answer (score 0):

You have to use select for this. Like in the communicate method of the subprocess.
There's a discussion about this in the [python issue tracker](http://bugs.python.org/issue1191964).

Answer (score 0):

THE DEAL: http://code.activestate.com/recipes/440554/